# Create clustered or nonclustered index on 1 million rows table for LIKE query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have a database table with postal codes, city, long, lat, province.

I have one use for this table which is to return suggested codes (plus city and province) for an autocomplete widget.

`city` and `postalcode` make up a unique record. I am starting the query at 3 characters.

This query is slow which makes the autocomplete experience bad. I am wondering given the information above what kind of Index would work best? I am using Azure SQL datastore and as such i am unable to run Query Analyzer/Tuning Advisor.

I have tried nonclustered index on `postalCode` and a 2 column clustered index on `postalCode` and `city`. Both yielded same results on a query:

```
Select * 
From PostalCode 
Where code LIKE '%L6J 0%'
```

I am not updating or inserting on this table.

Comment: That UK postcode looks like you could drop the prefix wildcard. In some database engines that will make a big speed difference - are you able to do that for the functionality you want? I don't know if there is any value in matching the first few letters to "anywhere in the postcode", since people will always type them from the first letter.

Comment: If you use a **leading** `%` in a `LIKE` comparison, no index whatsoever will be able to help you. This will **always** result in a full table scan

Comment: really good point.. I'm actually using EF/linq so it's a startswith. Which likely doesn't put that there. I don't know why i was testing with that in SQL Server manager but you are 100% correct. MUCH faster with Clustered Index on code and city and no leading %

Comment: If you use a leading `%` in a `LIKE` comparison the database _could_ use an **index** scan rather than a **table** scan. It's still not going to be pretty, but the wider the rows the better an index scan looks.

Comment: @billyjean:You could make use of Full text search

Comment: or you could also use Azure search service :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the length of postcode is fairly short and known (8), this is a good candidate for chunking.  Break the postcode up into all its constituent chunks and store them with their starting position and lengths to enable index seeks.

So for example, for a postcode such as 'OX1 1JZ', store all the following strings:

```
start len postcodePart
1   2   OX
1   3   OX1
1   4   OX11
1   5   OX11J
1   6   OX11JZ
2   2   X1
2   3   X11
2   4   X11J
2   5   X11JZ
3   2   11
3   3   11J
3   4   11JZ
4   2   1J
4   3   1JZ
5   2   JZ
```

Here is a sample script demonstrating the technique and how to shred the postcodes, using 100 sample postcodes and a trigger.

**NB!!** This is not production ready code, just a sample to show the technique.

```
USE tempdb
GO

-- https://www.postcodelist.co.uk/
--uk-postcodes.csv

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.postCodeParts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.postCodeParts
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.postCodes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.postCodes
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.postCodes (
    postcodeId              INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_postCodes PRIMARY KEY,
    postcode                VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL

    --... the rest of your columns

    )
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.postCodeParts (
    postcodePartId          INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_postCodeParts PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    postcodeId              INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.postCodes ( postcodeId ),

    totalLen                TINYINT NOT NULL,
    xStart                  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    xLen                    TINYINT NOT NULL,
    postcodePart            VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL INDEX cdx_postCodeParts CLUSTERED

    )
GO


-- Add a trimmed copy of the postcode to the parts table, chunked up.
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_postCodes
ON dbo.postcodes
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ) 
        ) x(y)
    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.postCodeParts ( postcodeId, totalLen, xStart, xLen, postcodePart )
    SELECT 
        p.postcodeId, 
        p.xTotalLen, 
        c1.y AS xstart, 
        c2.y AS xlen, 
        SUBSTRING( p.postCode, c1.y, c2.y ) AS xstring
    FROM ( 
        SELECT
            postcodeId,
            REPLACE( postcode, ' ', '' ) postCode, 
            LEN( REPLACE( postcode, ' ', '' ) ) AS xTotalLen 
        FROM inserted 
    ) p
        CROSS JOIN cte c1
            CROSS JOIN cte c2
    WHERE c2.y Between 2 And p.xTotalLen
      AND ( ( c2.y ) + ( c1.y - 1 ) ) <= p.xTotalLen

END
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.postcodes ( postcode )
VALUES
    ( 'OX1 1AA' ),( 'OX1 1AB' ),( 'OX1 1AD' ),( 'OX1 1AE' ),( 'OX1 1AF' ),( 'OX1 1AG' ),( 'OX1 1AN' ),( 'OX1 1AS' ),( 'OX1 1AW' ),( 'OX1 1AY' ),
    ( 'OX1 1AZ' ),( 'OX1 1BD' ),( 'OX1 1BE' ),( 'OX1 1BN' ),( 'OX1 1BP' ),( 'OX1 1BS' ),( 'OX1 1BT' ),( 'OX1 1BU' ),( 'OX1 1BX' ),( 'OX1 1BY' ),
    ( 'OX1 1BZ' ),( 'OX1 1DA' ),( 'OX1 1DB' ),( 'OX1 1DE' ),( 'OX1 1DF' ),( 'OX1 1DG' ),( 'OX1 1DJ' ),( 'OX1 1DL' ),( 'OX1 1DP' ),( 'OX1 1DQ' ),
    ( 'OX1 1DS' ),( 'OX1 1DW' ),( 'OX1 1DZ' ),( 'OX1 1EA' ),( 'OX1 1EF' ),( 'OX1 1EJ' ),( 'OX1 1EN' ),( 'OX1 1EP' ),( 'OX1 1EQ' ),( 'OX1 1ER' ),
    ( 'OX1 1ES' ),( 'OX1 1ET' ),( 'OX1 1EU' ),( 'OX1 1EW' ),( 'OX1 1EX' ),( 'OX1 1GA' ),( 'OX1 1GB' ),( 'OX1 1GD' ),( 'OX1 1GE' ),( 'OX1 1GF' ),
    ( 'OX1 1GH' ),( 'OX1 1GJ' ),( 'OX1 1GL' ),( 'OX1 1HB' ),( 'OX1 1HD' ),( 'OX1 1HF' ),( 'OX1 1HG' ),( 'OX1 1HH' ),( 'OX1 1HN' ),( 'OX1 1HP' ),
    ( 'OX1 1HQ' ),( 'OX1 1HR' ),( 'OX1 1HS' ),( 'OX1 1HT' ),( 'OX1 1HU' ),( 'OX1 1HW' ),( 'OX1 1HX' ),( 'OX1 1HY' ),( 'OX1 1HZ' ),( 'OX1 1JA' ),
    ( 'OX1 1JB' ),( 'OX1 1JD' ),( 'OX1 1JE' ),( 'OX1 1JF' ),( 'OX1 1JG' ),( 'OX1 1JH' ),( 'OX1 1JJ' ),( 'OX1 1JL' ),( 'OX1 1JP' ),( 'OX1 1JQ' ),
    ( 'OX1 1JR' ),( 'OX1 1JS' ),( 'OX1 1JT' ),( 'OX1 1JU' ),( 'OX1 1JW' ),( 'OX1 1JX' ),( 'OX1 1JY' ),( 'OX1 1JZ' ),( 'OX1 1LB' ),( 'OX1 1LD' ),
    ( 'OX1 1LE' ),( 'OX1 1LF' ),( 'OX1 1LG' ),( 'OX1 1LJ' ),( 'OX1 1LL' ),( 'OX1 1LQ' ),( 'OX1 1LT' ),( 'OX1 1LU' ),( 'OX1 1LY' ),( 'OX1 1ND' )
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.postCodes
SELECT * FROM dbo.postCodeParts ORDER BY xStart, xLen

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.postCodes pc
    INNER JOIN dbo.postCodeParts pcp ON pc.postcodeId = pcp.postcodeId
WHERE postcodePart = '1J'
ORDER BY xStart, xLen
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_searchPostCodes') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.usp_searchPostCodes
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_searchPostCodes

    @searchString   VARCHAR(8)

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --!!TODO add error handling
    --!!TODO does not deal with middle wildcards or _ wildcard

    DECLARE @leadingWildCard BIT
    DECLARE @cleanSearchString VARCHAR(8)

    SELECT @leadingWildCard = CASE WHEN LEFT( @searchString, 1 ) = '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT @cleanSearchString = REPLACE( REPLACE( @searchString, ' ', '' ), '%', '' )

    -- Debugging
    --PRINT @leadingWildCard
    --PRINT @cleanSearchString

    IF @leadingWildCard = 0

        -- No leading wildcard, start at position 1
        SELECT pc.postcode
        FROM dbo.postCodes pc
            INNER JOIN dbo.postCodeParts pcp ON pc.postcodeId = pcp.postcodeId
        WHERE pcp.postcodePart = @cleanSearchString
          AND pcp.xstart = 1
        ORDER BY xStart, xLen

    ELSE

        -- Leading wildcard, return all positions
        SELECT pc.postcode
        FROM dbo.postCodes pc
            INNER JOIN dbo.postCodeParts pcp ON pc.postcodeId = pcp.postcodeId
        WHERE pcp.postcodePart = @cleanSearchString
        ORDER BY xStart, xLen

RETURN
GO


EXEC dbo.usp_searchPostCodes 'OX1 1J%'
EXEC dbo.usp_searchPostCodes '%X1 1J%'
GO


SELECT xStart, xLen, postcodePart
FROM dbo.postCodes pc
    INNER JOIN dbo.postCodeParts pcp ON pc.postcodeId = pcp.postcodeId
WHERE pc.postcode= 'OX1 1JZ'
ORDER BY xStart, xLen
```

Comment: Any view on this?

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry just revisited today. yes i'm still not getting the performance i wanted.. so i started thinking about breaking the pcode up. This is way beyond what i was thinking. This looks really interesting. So the trigger is for populating the postCodeParts table? I already have the postalcodes table. Also implementing this.. how do you actually query it? Thanks Bob!

Comment: Work through my code example, it shows how to query it.

Comment: What about just adding 6 columns to the postalCode table. pcode1, pcode2,pcode3, pcode4, pcode5

Comment: Do not do that.  Apart from the fact it does not capture all combinations it would be bad design.  Ever heard of Normalization?

Comment: It does capture all the combinations because my queries are always a 'startswith' type query. Always. In terms of normalization you might be right but the postalcode table serves only to validate a postalcode. It's not serving any other purpose? Given those two points do you still think it's a terrible idea? I think your solution is absolutely complete and addresses requirements and use cases i don't and won't have. Performance wise, understanding my use case, do you still think it's better for me?

Comment: I'm also going to have problems using a stored procedure.

Comment: lol ok, I think your idea would have problems because, try writing the query to say 'OR p1 OR p2 OR p3 ...' - is it ugly?  The Stored Proc is just a wrapper for a query - are you executing query dynamically, say via a webpage?  You don't 100% need it but is a good practice, ie code is pre-compiled, kept in one place, modular etc

Comment: ha no doubt i hear you. Your solution is the most complete and definitely represents best practice. Which is why i marked it the correct answer. That said i wouldn't need an OR. The query would be prepared in the DA layer. A data access layer full of other business logic. The query would look like where input = postalcode.associatedPartialPostalcodeColumn. Really simple.

Comment: Well it's up to you in the end.  Call it how you see it.  In my experience, taking a shortcut normally leads to an issue sooner or later.  Good luck!